# Collapsing sum of variable conditional on another variable

Tags: stata

I am working with the CES diary data from 2006. I have a file which for each household has an entry for each item bought during a week long period. I have the following variables

`newid` id of household

`cost`  dollar cost of item

`ucc`   a code denoting the type of item

I am interested in restaurant expenditures which is covered by `ucc` 190111, 190112, ... . I want to `collapse` my data so for each `newid` I have the sum of restaurant expenditures for the household during the week. I used the command

```
 collapse (sum) cost if ucc=="190111".... , by (newid)
```

However, I would like to have a zero when there are no restaurant expenditures and Stata simply removes those entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an intermediate variable with some zeros for non-restaurant expenditures:

```
gen rest_exp = cond(inlist(ucc,"190111","190112"),cost,0)
collapse (sum) rest_exp, by(newid)
```

One caveat is that `inlist()` has a constraint of 9 possible values for strings, but you probably have fewer than that or should `destring`, in which case the limit is 254. You can also hitch a few `inlist()`s together with `|`.